# Condition for the intersection of straight line and cubic curve

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, geometry

I want to find out the conditions in terms of constants $a,h, b$ and $c$ for which the straight line $y= a(x-h)$ cuts the cubic curve $y=x(x-b)(x-c)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "cut"? The solutions to $a(x - h) = x (x - b) (x - c)$ are the roots of a cubic polynomial, and every cubic polynomial has at least one real root, and as many as three. Are you looking for a condition such that the line intersects the cubic curve in three places?

Comment: I am interested in those the intersections of the cubic curve and straight line given in the problem which occurs in positive quadrant. Here a, h, b and c are all positive constants and b<c. When b<h<c, then there will be only one such intersection. But when  h<b there may be one, two or no intersections. I want to determine the conditions when there will be one, two or no intersections in positive quadrant? but i could not find.

Comment: By 'positive quadrant' do you mean that you want both the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the intersection to be in the first quadrant? Or just that $x > 0$? Either way, this gives the problem a rather different flavor, and this constraint (as well as the constraints that $a, b, c, h > 0$ and $b < c$) should certainly be mentioned in the question itself, so that others don't spend time answering something you're not interested in.

Comment: I mean the first quadrant x>0, y>0.

Comment: Certainly $h < c$ is sufficient, as $a(c - h) > c(b - c)(c - c) = 0$ but, regarded as a function of $x$, the cubic expression grows faster than the linear one in the limit. It is not, however, sufficient. Consider, e.g., $b = 1, c = 2, h = 3$ and $a$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 2):

If $y=ax$ and also $y=x(x-b)(x-c)$ then either $x=0$ or else $a=(x-b)(x-c).$ The latter is just a quadratic equation, so use the discriminant.

In view of the solution $x=0,$ one could say the answer is that the line *always* cuts the cubic curve.

Oops, now the equation has been changed to the line being $y=a(x-h).$ After putting that in, one just gets another cubic curve back. But since the right side starts out $x^3,$ after subtracting $a(x-h)$ one has a monic cubic polynomial in $x$ which must always have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

OP specified in the comments under the original question that $a, b, c, h > 0$, that $b < c$, and that we're looking only for intersections of the two curves in the first quadrant.

It's convenient to regard the linear and cubic curves as graphs of functions, say, $L(x)$ and $C(x)$, respectively. Note that if $h < c$, then
$L(c) = a (c - h) > 0 = c (b - c) (c - c) = C(c)$, but $L$ is increasing and $C$ grows faster than $L$ as $x \to \infty$, so the curves intersect somewhere in the first quadrant to the right of $c$. Exploiting similar considerations, it's easy to see that the curves intersect at two points in the first quadrant if $h < b$ (including exactly once in the interval $(h, b)$) and at only one if $b \leq h < c$.

Treating the case $h \geq c$ seems to be more involved. In terms of the functions we've named, the intersections of the curves correspond to the roots of the difference $$D(x) := C(x) - L(x) = x^3 - (b + c) x^2 + (bc - a) x - a h$$ of the functions. This difference is itself a cubic function, and we know that it has a local minimum (because it has a local maximum between $0$ and $b$). By the first derivative test, this occurs at the larger of the two zeroes of $$D'(x) = 3 x^2 - 2 (b + c) x + (bc - a),$$ namely, at (via the Quadratic Formula)
$$m := \frac{1}{3} \left[b + c + \sqrt{(b + c)^2 - 3(b c - a)}\right].$$

If $m < c$ (or equivalently, after some rearrangement, if $a < c (c - b)$), then any positive roots $r$ of $D(x)$ satisfy $C(r) = L(r) < 0$, that is, the intersections are not in the first quadrant.

If $m = c$, then the line is tangent to the cubic curve (and so the curves have an intersection point of multiplicity $2$) at $(c, 0)$, which is in the closed first quadrant but not the open first quadrant.

On the other hand, if $m > c$, then since $C(c) = 0$ and $C(x)$ is increasing on $(c, \infty)$, any intersections are in the first quadrant as desired. To test whether there are any intersections, it's enough to determine the sign of the local minimum of $D(x)$, namely, $D(m)$ (which we can write out as a rather complicated expression in terms of the constants $a, b, c, h$ alone). If $D(m) < 0$, then since $D(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, $D$ has one root each in $(c, m)$ and $(m, \infty)$, and so there are two intersections in the first quadrant. If $D(m) = 0$, then the line is tangent to the curve at the point $(m, C(m))$ in the first quadrant, which again is an intersection of multiplicity two. Finally, if $D(m) < 0$, then there are no intersections at all in the first quadrant.

In summary, in all cases intersections refers to those in the *open* first quadrant:

- $h < b$: two intersections, one in $(h, b)$ and one in $(c, \infty)$
- $b \leq h < c$: one intersection in $(c, \infty)$
- $h = c$       : one intersection (in $(c, \infty)$) if $c^2 - 2 b c + bc > 2 a$, none otherwise
- $h > c$, $D(m) < 0$: two intersections, one in $(c, m)$ and one in $(m, \infty)$
- $h > c$, $D(m) = 0$: an intersection of multiplicity $2$ at $(m, C(m))$
- $h > c$, $D(m) > 0$: no intersections